# MPI_ERR_BUFFER from MPI_Bsend after removing following print statement?

Tags: c, mpi

I have the following code which works:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  int world_rank, world_size;
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

  int n = 10000;
  int ni, i;

  double t[n];
  int x[n];

  int buf[n];
  int buf_size = n*sizeof(int);
  MPI_Buffer_attach(buf, buf_size);

  if (world_rank == 0) {
    for (ni = 0; ni < n; ++ni) {
      int msg_size = ni;
      int msg[msg_size];
      for (i = 0; i < msg_size; ++i) {
        msg[i] = rand();
      }

      double time0 = MPI_Wtime();
      MPI_Bsend(&msg, msg_size, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      t[ni] = MPI_Wtime() - time0;
      x[ni] = msg_size;
      MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      printf("P0 sent msg with size %d\n", msg_size);
    }
  }

  else if (world_rank == 1) {
    for (ni = 0; ni < n; ++ni) {
      int msg_size = ni;
      int msg[msg_size];
      MPI_Request request;
      MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Irecv(&msg, msg_size, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
      MPI_Wait(&request, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
      printf("P1 received msg with size %d\n", msg_size);
    }
  }
  MPI_Buffer_detach(&buf, &buf_size);
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

As soon as I remove the print statements, the program crashes, telling me there is a `MPI_ERR_BUFFER: invalid buffer pointer`. If I remove only one of the print statements the other print statements are still executed, so I believe it crashes at the end of the program. I don't see why it crashes and the fact that it does not crash when I am using the print statements goes beyond my logic...

Would anybody have a clue what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply not providing enough buffer space to MPI. In buffered mode, all ongoing messages are stored in the buffer space which is used as a ring buffer. In your code, there can be multiple messages that need to be buffered, regardless of the `printf`. Note that not even `2*n*sizeof(int)` would be enough buffer space - the barriers do not provide a guarantee that the buffer is locally freed even though the corresponding receive is completed. You would have to provide `(n*(n-1)/2)*sizeof(int)` memory to be sure, or something in-between and hope.

Bottom line: **Don't use buffered mode.**

Generally, use **standard blocking** send calls and write the application such that it doesn't deadlock. Tune the MPI implementation such that small messages regardless of the receiver - to avoid wait times on late receivers.

If you want to overlap communication and computation, use **nonblocking** messages - providing proper memory for each communication.

Comment: The buffered mode buffers only messages that are not sent immediately, i.e. messages that would otherwise synchronously block the standard send.

Comment: @zulan Thanks for the answer. I did not know that have to provide space for _all_ messages at once. In the above code I try to force buffering because I want to measure performance differences between ready send and buffer send (not sure whether this is a reasonable thing to do - but proof of the pudding is the eating :P).

Comment: @Hristo - as I think I had understood from the MPI documentation, in standard mode MPI decides whether it buffers or sends and the buffered and ready mode allow me to specify the behaviour, did I get that wrong?

Comment: @HristoIliev I don't even find that promise in the standard (only that "if a send is executed and no matching receive is posted, then MPI must buffer the outgoing message, so as to allow the send call to complete."). Nevertheless, I think it's very difficult to deduce a actual upper limit for the buffer in most cases. Would you not agree with my recommendation?

Comment: Not sure if it's good manners to ask in one question for an answer to another question - but I also adress this buffered vs. ready question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098567/influence-of-send-modes-to-mpi-overhead-in-non-blocking-point-to-point-communica) - if any of you could tell me more about it I'd be very grateful.

Comment: All I'm saying is that the buffered mode is not required to buffer each and every message. And that's actually what some MPI implementations do. The OP's program runs fine even if no buffer is attached at all (which MPI treats as buffer size of zero) when run with Open MPI using the `tcp` BTL, which has an eager limit of 64 KiB. At the same time, it crashes immediately with Intel MPI. But I agree that it is a poorly understood mode and should be avoided in general.